# Pyspark - %Run magic command in Synapse Notebook: pass dynamic parameter

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse, spark-notebook, azure-notebooks

In synapse notebook, I'm using the %run magic command to running a notebook and it is running well:

```
%run "5 Bronze to silver/Daily/NB_B2S" { "exclude_bronze_notebook_names": '["NB_B2S_SNOW_Task", "NB_B2S_Time_and_Resources_Task_Time"]' }
```

but when I tried to to pass the values dynamically trough parameter, for example:

```
bronze_notebook_names = ['NB_B2S_SNOW_Task', 'NB_B2S_Time_and_Resources_Task_Time']

%run "5 Bronze to silver/Daily/NB_B2S" { "exclude_bronze_notebook_names": bronze_notebook_names }
```

It returns an error:

> MagicUsageError: Cannot parse notebook parameters. More details please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2173018
> --> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: b. Path 'exclude_bronze_notebook_names', line 1, position 35.

The alternative would be to use `mssparkutils.notebook.run()`, but I want to use %run.

Is there any way to achieve this with %run magic command?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the mssparkuntils command. The %run magic command does not directly support passing dynamic parameters to the script or notebook being run.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a different notebook in synapse while also supplying dramatic parameters by using the following code:

```
timeout_duration = 90
dynamic_parameters = {}
dynamic_parameters['example_parameter'] = 'val'
mssparkutils.notebook.run('notebook_name', timeout_duration , dynamic_parameters)
```

Use this for further reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python